# How do I define team membership of columns

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have imported a dataset from a csv which contains match statistics of League of Legends games (https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/league-of-legends).
I want to to apply Machine Learning algorithms on the Champion IDs and the outcome of the match.
As each champion ID is listed in a column I created 2 lists (t1, t2) which contain the champion IDs of each team member.

But when calling  knn.fit I receive the error message "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."
If I understood correctly KNN needs single values and not lists.
But I don't know how to model my dataframe in another way that I have the team membership.

```
data = pd.read_csv('resources/LoL/games.csv', delimiter=',')

data['t1'] = data[['t1_champ1id', 't1_champ2id', 't1_champ3id', 't1_champ4id', 't1_champ5id']].values.tolist()
data['t2'] = data[['t2_champ1id', 't2_champ2id', 't2_champ3id', 't2_champ4id', 't2_champ5id']].values.tolist()

reduceddata = pd.DataFrame(data[['t1', 't2']])
outcomes = data[['winner']]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test= train_test_split(reduceddata,outcomes['winner'], random_state=0)
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to select your columns(features) in this way:

```
reduceddata = data[['t1_champ1id', 't1_champ2id', 't1_champ3id', 't1_champ4id', 't1_champ5id', 't2_champ1id', 't2_champ2id', 't2_champ3id', 't2_champ4id', 't2_champ5id']]
outcomes = data['winner']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test= train_test_split(reduceddata, outcomes, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Apparently this is what I did in my first try until I noticed that this will just apply a bunch of IDs(champions) to the algorithm without the specific context which shows which team they belong to.